# ar command line length

Tags: android, linker, bjam, binutils, unix-ar

I have an extremely long command line given to ***ar*** (android ar exactly) by bjam, and ar just corrupts a file path and complains that file does not exist.

Is there a way to make ar allocate a bigger command line buffer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the Android version but many `ar` implementations (and indeed many *other* commands) allow you to put all your arguments into a file (say `xyz.opt`) and then use something like `ar @xyz.opt` to do the grunt work.

That works because the limitation tends to be not so much on the program itself but often on the shell constructing the argument list. By placing the arguments into a file, you can effectively get around that limitation.

Comment: I've tried to add your solution but bjam just won't cooperate with me. When I try to redirect the command arguments to say a 'xyz.opt' file only 2 paths get into the file. Bjam has caused me a lot of gray hairs over the time.

Comment: If it's bjam giving you grief, you have two options: (1) persevere and learn; or (2) ditch it for something else, hopefully that you either already know or is easy to learn. Me, I'd go for option 2 but that's simply because I'm used to regular makes.